# Getting sequence based on locus tag ID - SnakeMake

Tags: python, snakemake

I hope this type of programming question is allowed within the StackOverflow guidelines, otherwise please correct me if I am wrong!

I have been working on a workflow in snakemake with bio informatics purposes. The file which I have now is a text file with a wide range of locus tags. I need to get the sequences from these locus tags. I have been studying the documentation of snakemake and are yet unable to find the right function of libary to retrieve the sequences based on the locus tag and organism... The code which I have now:

```
rule get_id:
    input:
        a="RNA-Seq-counts.txt"
    output:
        b="output.txt"
    shell:
        "python RetrieveFirstColumn.py {input} {output}"
```

The output of output.txt

```
lp_0001
lp_0002
lp_0004
lp_0005
lp_0009
lp_0010
lp_0011
lp_0012
lp_0013
lp_0014
lp_0015
lp_0016
lp_0017
```

Comment: Hi, 
I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do but it looks it's something more related to BioPython or such maybe. What are the contents of RNA-Seq-counts.txt and RetrieveFirstColumn.py?

Comment: To clarify, Snakemake is just a generic workflow management system. Your Snakemake rule looks correct, but the problem you have has to be solved within the Python script you use there.